# Drupal - error installing module "entity"

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have a Drupal installation within a Docker container, with Composer and Drush installed. I'd like to install the Entity-API module (https://www.drupal.org/project/entity), and I start off with:
`composer require drupal/entity`
This gives me an error:

```
Using version ^0.1.0 for drupal/entity
./composer.json has been updated
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.5.6, 8.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.0.x-dev, 8.5.6].
    - Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.0.x-dev, 8.5.6].
    - drupal/entity 0.1.0 requires drupal/core <8.1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for drupal/entity ^0.1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/entity[0.1.0].
    - Installation request for drupal/core (locked at 8.5.6, required as ~8.5.3) -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.5.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

My Drupal version is 8.5.6 and I'm using the latest version of Composer, installed from https://getcomposer.org/installer

How would I get this installed using Composer? Tx

Answer (score 0):

Use `--update-with-all-dependencies` switch:

```
composer require drupal/entity --update-with-all-dependencies
```

> - `--update-with-all-dependencies`: Also update dependencies of the newly required packages, including those that are root requirements.
>
> <sub>https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require</sub>